# Failed to BuildAndStart gRPC server tensorflow serving

Tags: docker, grpc, tensorflow-serving

run command:

```sh
docker run -it --rm  -p 8501:8501 \
-v "$(pwd)/saved_model:/models/docker_test" \
-e MODEL_NAME=docker_test tensorflow/serving
```

log:

2020-03-27 03:47:12.744007: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:87] Successfully loaded servable version {name: docker_test version: 1}
E0327 03:47:12.745641810       6 server_chttp2.cc:40]        {"created":"@1585280832.745604945","description":"No address added out of total 1 resolved","file":"external/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/chttp2_server.cc","file_line":348,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1585280832.745604216","description":"Failed to add any wildcard listeners","file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_posix.cc","file_line":324,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1585280832.745598444","description":"Address family not supported by protocol","errno":97,"file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":379,"os_error":"Address family not supported by protocol","syscall":"socket","target_address":"[::]:8500"},{"created":"@1585280832.745603685","description":"Permission denied","errno":13,"file":"external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":379,"os_error":"Permission denied","syscall":"socket","target_address":"0.0.0.0:8500"}]}]}
Failed to start server. Error: Invalid argument: Failed to BuildAndStart gRPC server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try opening port 8500 for gRPC using the below docker run :-

docker run -it --rm  -p 8501:8501 
-p 8500:8500 
-v "$(pwd)/saved_model:/models/docker_test" 
-e MODEL_NAME=docker_test tensorflow/serving